# Appium:Unable To Find Element

Tags: android, appium

I have done Appium setup with Android Studio. I am able to launch app but unable to find element as a button or textview.

Here is my gradle file.

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.10'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
implementation files('libs/byte-buddy-1.8.3.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/guava-23.6-jre.jar')
implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.5.3.jar')
implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.4.6.jar')
implementation files('libs/okhttp-3.9.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/okio-1.13.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.12.0-sources.jar')
implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.12.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/java-client-6.0.0.jar')
```

Here is my test file.

```
RemoteWebDriver driver;
@Before
public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {

    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0.0");// Pixel
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.ebay.mobile");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.ebay.mobile.activities.MainActivity");

    // Instantiate Appium Driver
    try {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
@Test
public void testIfEBaySearchAvailable() {

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.name("SIGN IN")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("Search for anything")).click();
}
```

}

Here is error which I am getting.

```
    F:\Android\Android_Setups\android-studio-ide-143.2790544-windows\android-studio\jre\bin\java -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -Didea.launcher.port=53087 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=F:\Android\Android_Setups\android-studio-ide-143.2790544-windows\android-studio\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath F:\Android\Android_Setups\android-studio-ide-143.2790544-windows\android-studio\lib\idea_rt.jar;F:\Android\Android_Setups\android-studio-ide-143.2790544-windows\android-studio\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;F:\Android\Android_Setups\AndroidSdk\AndroidSdk\platforms\android-27\data\res;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\build\intermediates\classes\test\debug;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\animated-vector-drawable-27.1.1.aar\97c0160fe173c1eb1e77c4b8fee42635\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\c905d0bd51dfa2168208e1142263aed1\res;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\c905d0bd51dfa2168208e1142263aed1\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.1\860340562250678d1a344907ac75754e259cdb14\hamcrest-core-1.1.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\byte-buddy-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.core\common\1.1.0\8007981f7d7540d89cd18471b8e5dcd2b4f99167\common-1.1.0.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\httpcore-4.4.6.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\commons-codec-1.10.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\commons-logging-1.2.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\httpclient-4.5.3.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\constraint-layout-1.1.0.aar\2ec91a3302209fd49d42034ca4133402\res;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\constraint-layout-1.1.0.aar\2ec91a3302209fd49d42034ca4133402\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support.constraint\constraint-layout-solver\1.1.0\931532e953a477f876f2de18c2e7f16eee01078f\constraint-layout-solver-1.1.0.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\client-combined-3.12.0-sources.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-vector-drawable-27.1.1.aar\da7d1cfef6afb9defe897425aa321eed\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.0.aar\cf9212e0fb1c62d642cd19dfeab937e0\jars\classes.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\okhttp-3.9.1.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.lifecycle\common\1.1.0\edf3f7bfb84a7521d0599efa3b0113a0ee90f85\common-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.10\e4f1766ce7404a08f45d859fb9c226fc9e41a861\junit-4.10.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\guava-23.6-jre.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\java-client-6.0.0.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar\90e51c77499731d2386df5f896a90684\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar\90e51c77499731d2386df5f896a90684\res;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\730e0fd60e7316c1cd8988b484b608b6\res;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-27.1.1.aar\730e0fd60e7316c1cd8988b484b608b6\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\viewmodel-1.1.0.aar\3eb742d286119fdd6f14adfe71e13ddd\jars\classes.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\okio-1.13.0.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\livedata-core-1.1.0.aar\d107b006abfdde5437c7aa9690e097df\jars\classes.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\gson-2.8.2.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-utils-27.1.1.aar\59acfae8dd42985675b0190ed39a72e9\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-fragment-27.1.1.aar\6987b3584a7fa4fc091439dfe90bd43e\jars\classes.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\libs\client-combined-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\support-annotations\27.1.1\39ded76b5e1ce1c5b2688e1d25cdc20ecee32007\support-annotations-27.1.1.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.0.aar\d027a275dfc22e0b4feb1e5305d6fd0a\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\sandy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\multidex-1.0.3.aar\f735cffb58b1a5290f5b402162f34341\jars\classes.jar;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\build\intermediates\sourceFolderJavaResources\test\debug;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\build\intermediates\sourceFolderJavaResources\debug;F:\Android\workspace\Appium_Assignment\app\build\generated\mockable-android-27.v3.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2 com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 sandy.com.appium_assignment.EBayAppiumTest,testIfEBaySearchAvailable
Jun 02, 2018 5:14:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {error=invalid selector, message=Locator Strategy 'name' is not supported for this session, stacktrace=InvalidSelectorError: Locator Strategy 'name' is not supported for this session
    at AndroidDriver.validateLocatorStrategy (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\basedriver\driver.js:328:13)
    at AndroidDriver.callee$0$0$ (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\basedriver\commands\find.js:19:8)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    at invoke (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
    at enqueueResult (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:185:17)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\$.export.js:30:36)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:184:12)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:209:12)
    at AndroidDriver.callee$0$0 [as findElOrElsWithProcessing] (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\build\lib\basedriver\commands\find.js:35:30)
    at AndroidDriver.callee$0$0$ (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\basedriver\commands\find.js:35:21)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    at invoke (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
    at enqueueResult (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:185:17)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\$.export.js:30:36)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:184:12)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:209:12)
    at AndroidDriver.callee$0$0 [as findElement] (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\build\lib\basedriver\commands\find.js:76:30)
    at C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\basedriver\driver.js:275:26
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:510:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:584:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAtPostResolution (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:248:10)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:128:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:133:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:15:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)}
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-A5G86II', ip: '192.168.0.104', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_152-release'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:324)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:395)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:284)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:309)
    at sandy.com.appium_assignment.EBayAppiumTest.testIfEBaySearchAvailable(EBayAppiumTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
    ... 33 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

I am able to launch app but mu test case getting fail with above error.

Here is screenshot from uiautomatorviewer

[image: snapshot from uiautomatorviewer]

Comment: You can try by suing `xpath` like `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='SIGN IN']")).click();` or by text like `driver.findElement(new By.ByName("SIGN IN")).click();`

Comment: I tried all way to find element.

Comment: can you add the screenshot with UIAutomatorViewer ?

Comment: @AlImran added snapshot. Please check

Comment: Have you tried with element ID? `button_sign_in`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Appium:

1. Stop using buggy UIAutomatorViewer, use official [appium-desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) inspector instead
2. `Name` is not supported locator strategy, for Appium-Android you can use

   - `MobileBy.id/By.id` when element has `resource-id` attribute
   - `MobileBy.AccessibilityId` when element has `content-desc` attribute
   - `MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator` to use search with [native UIAutomator java-written locator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector)
   - `By.xpath/By.className` are bad options in terms of stability/performance, but still can be used.

In your case best option is obvious:

`driver.findElement(By.id("button_sign_in")` is the best approach

Comment: Why did you mention By.xpath as bad option?
At least in Selenium By.xpath is same stable and fast as By.cssSelector

Comment: Because Appium is not Selenium, they just share the same concept of JSON Wire protocol. XPath is not native locator strategy so it requires an additional step to prepare XML representation of app screen and then search by provided XPath.

Comment: Appium-desktop is deprecated, but there's Appium Inspector now: https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector/releases

Answer (score 0):

By.name() doesn't work, try with findElementByAndroidUIAutomator:

```
public WebElement scrollByTextTo(String desc) {
    return driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0))" +
        ".scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(" + "\"" + desc + "\"" + "));");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Locating an element on mobile screen with appium don't work any more with strategy By.name("-----").

you can use 'resource-id' which as locator which is displayed in your uiautomator viewer screen. so you can use something like for 'Sign In' click

```
   driver.findElement(By.id("com.ebay.mobile:id/button_sign_in")).click();
```

OR by using XPATH

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[text()='SIGN IN']")).click();
```

You can use similar strategy for 'Search for Anything' element.